# Unexpected behaviour while using extension methods

Tags: c#, string

Why does this happen? Please observe the following code:

```
static class StringExtension
{
    public static string Remove(this string s, char c)
    {
        return s.Replace(c.ToString(), "");
    }
    public static string Remove(this string s, char[] a)
    {
        foreach (char c in a)
        {
            s = s.Remove((char)c); // <---- ArgumentOutOfRange Exception here
        }
        return s;
    }
}
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] a = new char[] { '.', ',' };

        string testString = "Clean.this,string.from,periods.and,commas.";

        Console.WriteLine(testString.Remove(a));

    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an ArgumentOutOfRange exception at the indicate line. Turns out that even if I have a specific code for an extension Remove (this, char) and I explicitly (although, there should be no reason for this) specify the parameter's type, it ignores my extension and tries to call the original Remove(int) method.

Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug in C#?

P.S. I use VS2010.

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to replace the string itself better use a copy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This line:

```
s.Remove((char) c);
```

is calling [`string.Remove(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx) - the compiler will always use an applicable instance method instead of an extension method if it can. It's applicable due to the implicit conversion from `char` to `int`. That's the method that's throwing the exception, because the argument you're passing it is out of range. (In fact, you're lucky - in a worse situation it would be *in* range, and returning entirely unexpected results.)

In general I would *strongly* advise you not to create extension methods which have the same names as instance methods on the extended type, *particularly* if they've got the same number of parameters. Working out overloading is hard enough in general without adding extension methods to the mix. Don't forget that whenever *you* can't easily work out what your code is doing, someone reading the code in a year's time is going to have a ten times harder job.

Comment: Just **HOW** you answer these questions before I even read them, I have no idea. o__o But +1, great answer. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: In this case I just got lucky; tonight's episode of the West Wing (on DVD) had just finished...